# develop mobile application - payment information

Tags: objective-c, ios, web-services, payment

We are about to develop new mobile application that requires the end user to fill his payment information, which will be redirected to a third party’s portal to pay for a certain services through the application ( using Web Services )

user send billing information using web services  , Is this legal for apple ?

Comment: what are the services you will sell?

Comment: i am a merchant , i get sign up fees and shipping  fees from customers

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to integrate 3rd party credit card payment systems in your app (for example PayPal, Amazon payments, etc. or your own system) as long as you *do not* sell services, extensions, etc. to your app. As you say you're going to sell *physical* goods, it is OK for Apple. Amazon app does the same thing. Btw it is even explicitly prohibited to use in-app payments to sell *physical* goods.

EDIT: more answer to the detailed questions in the comment

IMHO (see disclaimer):

- Shipping fees of physical goods and signup fees for your physical service are *NOT* services or extensions - in the sense that Apple uses it, it applies only to some additional features to your application, for example a new level in a game or a new map in a mapping app
- to be legally store, transmit, process credit card information, you will have to be compliant to the [Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard). Here Apple has nothing to do, but both Visa and Mastercard (and maybe also other card issuers) *require* that you implement these practices if you wish to process credit card data of their cards
- this last requirement might be tricky so I really suggest you to look for some ready solution instead of implementing your own. See also the first answer to this question: [Use In App Purchase For Real Goods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228869/use-in-app-purchase-for-real-goods)

DISCLAIMER: I am not a legal authority or somebody from Apple so I can give you just hints but not a legal advice - will have to ask a lawyer for an "official" answer :)

Comment: in my case, all what i need is to send the billing information to the server through webservice, the payment gateway is already implemented in the server side. so is it legal to do so? and does the shipping fees and signup fees are considered as services or extensions?

Comment: I added more info to the answer based on your additional questions